# Unique set of Entities in class with null values symfony / api-platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have an Entity as below:

```
 shape
 --------------
 ?float height
 ?float width
 ?float depth
```

I would like to limit the creation of objects to unique values, including combinations of null values
e.g:

```
shape1: 1,1,1
shape2: 1,null,null
shape3: 1,1,null
shape4: null,null,null
...
```

I have tried to add a UniqueEntity Constraint to do this:

```
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields={"height","width","depth"}
* )
```

But the validation only triggers when actual values are passed:

```
 id    height    width    depth
 1       1         1        1    <- triggers constraint if inserted twice
 2       1       null     null   <- does not trigger constraint if inserted twice
 3     null      null     null   <- does not trigger constraint if inserted twice
 4       1         1      null   <- triggers constraint if inserted twice
```

How can i fix this?
[ignoreNull](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#ignorenull) will ignore null values completely, or, if set to `=false`, will trigger after the first null value, again ignoring the field completely.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a [Class Constraint Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator). In it there might be something like:

```
public function validate($shape, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $same = false;
    $nulls = is_null($shape->getHeight()) + is_null($shape->getWidth()) + is_null($shape->getDepth());
    if ($shape->getHeight() === $shape->getWidth() || $shape->getHeight() === $shape->getDepth() || $shape->getWidth() === $shape->getDepth()) {
        $same = true;
    }
    if ($nulls > 1 || !$same) {
        return;
    }
    $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->atPath('foo')
            ->addViolation();
}
```

This, however, does not test whether a shape with identical dimensions already exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up creating a Class Constraint Validator like you said, then looping through the properties of the class. I'm going to create an answer with it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class Constraint Validator as @geoB suggested:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

// https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html
class RequiresUniqueEntityValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @var ManagerRegistry
     */
    private ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry
    )
    {
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $repository = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository(get_class($value));
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($value);
        $properties = $reflection->getProperties();
        $items = [];
        foreach ($properties as $property) {
            $propertyValue = $value->{"get" . ucfirst($property->name)}();
            $items[$property->name] = $propertyValue;
        }
        $result = $repository->findBy($items);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            // if an item was found, that means that it already exists -> raise Violation
            }
            $text = 'The Item with fields: is not unique';
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ notUnique }}', $text)
                ->atPath(get_class($value))
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```